# Firebase Hosting not updating connected domain

Tags: firebase, dns, firebase-hosting

I'm hosting a web app with Firebase hosting service.

I build my app and then deploy it using firebase command tools.

The build is successful and the firebase domain shows the update:
https://calmeet-a7271.firebaseapp.com/e/-KsC5suhESWNwzYw6rtq

But the connected domain doesn't show the update:
https://calmeet.co

You can see the difference in these two links by the Settings (cog) button on the top right. https://calmeet-a7271.firebaseapp.com/e/-KsC5suhESWNwzYw6rtq has the settings button while https://calmeet.co does not

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I thought this would be automatic.
DNS seem to be working alright. I don't see any error in firebase

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had this same issue. It was caused by doing back to back ng-build and firebase deploy commands in the terminal.

Turns out chrome was caching my connected site. If I opened it in a different browser (safari) it would update. Another way to fix it in chrome is to clear recent browsing data by going to your browser toolbar, clicking More and then More Tools and then Clear Browsing Data.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, Clear caching browse and try again or open another browser.

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

Just do a hard refresh (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>) on your website on Chrome. That worked for me.